# How to make a wicket link appear as an image?

Tags: java, wicket

I am trying to make a wicket link appear as an image instead of text.  I am creating an external link and then placing it on the page.

```
add(new ExternalLink("link", url, "Page name"));
<a wicket:id="link"></a>
```

My problem is that I can't put the image in place of "Page name" because it will just set the html as text.  I also tried to span a wicket id instead and it also is rendered as text.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9):

For a static image:

```
<a wicket:id="link"><img src="myImg.jpg" alt="My Image" /></a>
add(new ExternalLink("link", url));
```

Or for a dynamic image add the image to the ExternalLink

Answer (score 8):

For programatically set image:

HTML:

```
<a wicket:id="link"><img wicket:id="img"/></a>
```

Java:

```
ExternalLink link = new ExternalLink("link", url);
Image image = new Image("img", new SharedResourceReference(BasePage.class, "images/MyImage.png")
link.add(image);
add(link);
```