# using images for links with <wicket:link>

Tags: javascript, wicket

I'm trying to use an image for a link like so:

```
<wicket:link>
    <a href="UploadPage.html">
        <img src="/logo.png"/>
    </a>
</wicket:link>
```

In the rendered HTML, the `href` of the `<a>` is correctly set to my upload page.

But curiously, Wicket adds `onclick=window.location.href='/logo.png'` to the `<img>` tag. The end result is that clicking on the logo loads the logo itself, rather than the upload page.

A simple work-around is to not use `<wicket:link>`, and hard-code the url to my upload page, but I'd like to know if there is a proper solution to this.

Comment: I'm not sure but this sounds like an autolink bug.

Comment: @biziclop- I just filed a bug report on it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-3930

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it helped to add empty onClick (Wicket 1.5):

```
<li><a class="current" href="main">
   <img onClick="" src="img/icons/home.png"/>
</a></li>
```

after this, the link points to the page, not the image itself

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in your html:

```
<a wicket:id="linkID"><img src="/logo.png"/></a>
```

Add the following in the corresponding java class:

```
add(new PageLink<Void>("linkID", new YourWicketPage()));
```

Or for more generic purposes:

```
add(new Link<Void>("linkID") {
    @Override
    public void onClick()
    {
        // do whatever you want when the link/image is clicked
    }
);
```

Note that I gave the Link a Void model, since a model doesn't seem necessary to me in this case. However, it is imaginable that given a certain context a model for the link should be used.

Answer (score 0):

did you already check out the answer in [How to make a wicket link appear as an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070485/how-to-make-a-wicket-link-appear-as-an-image)

Which wicket version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Wicket 1.4.17. I'm only trying to link to an internal Wicket page, not an ExternalLink, so the page you reference doesn't really apply.

Comment: This is rather a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have maybe forgotten the quote on the "onclick" :

```
onclick="window.location.href='/logo.png'"
```

Comment: I'm not supplying the onclick behavior- Wicket is.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention: using full url for src tag should help (http://blah/logo.png) but it's not elegent or portable solution. Perhaps it's a wicket bug. Maybe consider using div with css instead?